# Jenkins plugin cannot see variables set using the withEnv workflow step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I want the gradle plugin to pick up environment variables that are set in a `withEnv` step (or other wrapper-types). When I invoke gradle using a `sh` step the variable is found, but when I use the gradle plugin it is not.

The gradle plugin performs the equivalent of this:

```
EnvVars env = run.getEnvironment(taskListener);
launcher.launch().cmds(args).envs(env).stdout(gca)
                        .pwd(rootLauncher).join();
```

The javadoc for run.getEnvironment() states:

> Returns the map that contains environmental variables to be used for
>   launching processes for this build. BuildSteps that invoke external
>   processes should use this. This allows BuildWrappers and other project
>   configurations (such as JDK selection) to take effect.
>
> Unlike earlier getEnvVars(), this map contains the whole environment,
>   not just the overrides, so one can introspect values to change its
>   behavior.

If I debug the plugin I see that there are less than a dozen variables in the environment passed to the gradle invocation, none of which are the variables `withEnv` should be providing. To the best I could tell, the `sh` step uses a completely different extension point, and is straight up given an instance of `EnvVars` that appears to be much more complete. I'm fairly certain the problem isn't in `withEnv`, but I don't see how to fix the gradle plugin.

Am I using the wrong call? Or perhaps the wrong extension point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not call `Run.getEnvironment`. Rather use the `EnvVars` passed to `SimpleBuildStep.perform`.

Comment: SimpleBuildStep.perform doesn't receive any EnvVars directly: [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep.html#perform). That's why I tried pulling them out of the Run object.

Comment: I see. Then `SimpleBuildStep` needs to be enhanced to specify an `EnvVars`, and your plugin would need to depend on a version of core with this enhanced API. I filed [JENKINS-29144](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29144) to track this.